# Add centered text to a figure

Tags: horizontal-alignment, text-manipulation

I'm trying to add some text to a tikz figure using the `\put` command, something like:

```
\put(-175,25){This text is too long}
```

Yet, if the text is too long, I would like to add it in several lines and **centered**. Is there an easy way to do this instead of breaking the above command in two:

```
\put(-175,25){This text is}
\put(-175,0){too long}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean pict2e instead of tikz?

Comment: It was text over a tikz figure.

Comment: And why not using TikZ nodes, for this?

Comment: Because I was already using the nodes in an array of figures, and I had to add text to specific locations in those nodes.

Comment: I don't quite see the problem of using a `node` for that though. This is ancient history now, but if you're still interested, add an example of what you had, and see if any TikZ answers occur.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem using:

```
\put(-175,25){ \parbox{4cm}{\centering This text is \\too long }}
```